# Image Overlay in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to create a Microsoft SharePoint page which will contain an image and then there will be a lot of other clickable images on top of it.  I am familiar with how to do this using HTML and CSS, but from what I can tell, SharePoint does not allow this type of image placement.  Can anyone give me some pointers on how to do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I was originally trying to just insert images onto the page editor, and then manually try to drag one image onto another.  This didn't work.  But then after some experimenting I found the Insert Code Snippet tool, which I then constructed a custom HTML image of exactly what I want. Worked perfectly.